# Sumproduct including a workday function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using this formula to determine if the date is column F occurs after the date in column G, but before the date in column G + 3 work days.

I was using the following formula which worked quite well:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($F$5:$F$1000>$G$5:$G$1000)*($F$5:$F$1000<($G$5:$G$1000+3)))
```

But I realized I was not accounting for weekends in the final "+3."

So I tried this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($F$5:$F$1000>$G$5:$G$1000)*($F$5:$F$1000<(WORKDAY($G$5:$G$1000,3))))
```

And it returns `#VALUE!`  This happens whether I push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or not.

How do I make this work please?

Comment: Provide some more details.

Comment: I am using this formula to determine if the date is column F occurs after the date in column G, but before the date in column G + 3 work days.

Comment: Try inserting a `+` sign into the formula to convert the range to an array: `WORKDAY(+$G$5:$G$1000,3)`

Comment: Lori_m, that worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As appointed by @Tim, the `workday` function cannot accept a range. But you can simulate what you need with the `weekday` function by using this:

```
If(weekday(G2:G5; x)>=y;5;3)
```

Where `x` is your code of sunday, `y` is Wednesday. If your working day is greater than wednesday, then you will sum 5, not 3.

```
=SUM(IF($F$2:$F$3 > $G$2:$G$3; 1; 0)*
     IF($F$2:$F$3 < $G$5:$G$1000 + IF(WEEKDAY($G$2:$G$3)>= Y ;5;3); 1; 0))
```

Weekday does accept a range, and it returns a range of weekdays. When you compute if (that also accepts a range) you create an 0/1 matrix (which is like your 
indicator matrix of rows where the condition is active). If you * both matrix of conditions, you will have the remaining rows that matches both conditions. And lastly, if you apply the sum, you will get the count.

This is a way to simulate `sumproduct` when you have conditions that requires a formula

You will have to use ctrl +shift + enter.

```
 03/09/2015 02/09/2015  
 07/09/2015 03/09/2015
```

Using this dates i obtained the result of 2. 
Which is correct, both dates are greater than their partners but lower than their partners + 3 working days

P.S: I use spanish Excel, so it can be mistakes of formula translating

Answer (score 1):

Lori_m, in the comments to my question provided a working answer:

Try inserting a + sign into the formula to convert the range to an array: WORKDAY(+$G$5:$G$1000,3) –  lori_m 17 hours ago

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `Start_Date` argument of the `WORKDAY` function cannot accept a range (eg `$G$5:$G$1000` in your code). I'm not exactly sure what your trying to do without more details and some sample data, so that's the best help I can give you.